# STM32F407VE Save 4 bytes in flash Issue

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, iar, stm32f407

4 bytes of new IP (type u32_t or uint32_t, IAR9.30.1) must be stored in flash memory to keep them until the next restart of the microcontroller.
Would you tell me how to save 4 bytes without using HAL?

Comment: Read the reference manual, or read how the HAL code does it and write code that does the exact same thing. But you might be missing the fact that you can easily store something once, and then it either needs erasing a whole block before writing again, or using some kind of mechanism to track latest of multiple writes to do some wear leveling. ST has an appnote for EEPROM emulation, have you read it?

Comment: Reference Manuals:  Embedded Flash memory in 
STM32F405xx/07xx....: The Flash memory has the following main features:....• Byte, half-word, word and double word write. Would you give an example of "• Byte, half-word, word and double word write" ?

Comment: Thank thee Justme.
Thy help was excellent. Thou art good and doest good.

Comment: The point of having the so-called "HAL" is that you can look at it and write your own drivers accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without using hal:

*eeprom.h*:

```c
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file    EEPROM_Emulation/inc/eeprom.h 
  * @author  MCD Application Team
   * @version V1.0.0
  * @date    10-October-2011
  * @brief   This file contains all the functions prototypes for the EEPROM 
  *          emulation firmware library.
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * THE PRESENT FIRMWARE WHICH IS FOR GUIDANCE ONLY AIMS AT PROVIDING CUSTOMERS
  * WITH CODING INFORMATION REGARDING THEIR PRODUCTS IN ORDER FOR THEM TO SAVE
  * TIME. AS A RESULT, STMICROELECTRONICS SHALL NOT BE HELD LIABLE FOR ANY
  * DIRECT, INDIRECT OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES WITH RESPECT TO ANY CLAIMS ARISING
  * FROM THE CONTENT OF SUCH FIRMWARE AND/OR THE USE MADE BY CUSTOMERS OF THE
  * CODING INFORMATION CONTAINED HEREIN IN CONNECTION WITH THEIR PRODUCTS.
  *
  * <h2><center>&copy; COPYRIGHT 2011 STMicroelectronics</center></h2>
  ******************************************************************************
  */ 

/* Define to prevent recursive inclusion -------------------------------------*/
#ifndef __EEPROM_H
#define __EEPROM_H

/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "stm32f4xx.h"

/* Exported constants --------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Define the size of the sectors to be used */
// #define PAGE_SIZE               (uint32_t)0x4000  /* Page size = 16KByte */ // minem
#define PAGE_SIZE               (uint32_t)0x20000  /* Page size = 128KByte; 128*1024 = 131072 to_hex-> 0x20000; PAGE_SIZE is an 7th sector size  */ // minem

/* Device voltage range supposed to be [2.7V to 3.6V], the operation will 
   be done by word  */
#define VOLTAGE_RANGE           (uint8_t)VoltageRange_3

/* EEPROM start address in Flash */
//#define EEPROM_START_ADDRESS  ((uint32_t)0x08008000) /* EEPROM emulation start address:
//                                                  from sector2 : after 16KByte of used 
//                                                  Flash memory */ // minem

#define EEPROM_START_ADDRESS  ((uint32_t)0x08040000) /* EEPROM emulation start address:
                                                  from sector6 : after 256KByte (16+16+16+16+64+128) of used 
                                                  Flash memory */ // minem

/* Pages 0 and 1 base and end addresses */
#define PAGE0_BASE_ADDRESS    ((uint32_t)(EEPROM_START_ADDRESS + 0x0000))
#define PAGE0_END_ADDRESS     ((uint32_t)(EEPROM_START_ADDRESS + (PAGE_SIZE - 1)))
// #define PAGE0_ID               FLASH_Sector_2 // minem
#define PAGE0_ID               FLASH_Sector_6 // minem

#define PAGE1_BASE_ADDRESS    ((uint32_t)(EEPROM_START_ADDRESS + 0x4000))
#define PAGE1_END_ADDRESS     ((uint32_t)(EEPROM_START_ADDRESS + (2 * PAGE_SIZE - 1)))
// #define PAGE1_ID               FLASH_Sector_3
#define PAGE1_ID               FLASH_Sector_7 // minem

/* Used Flash pages for EEPROM emulation */
#define PAGE0                 ((uint16_t)0x0000)
#define PAGE1                 ((uint16_t)0x0001)

/* No valid page define */
#define NO_VALID_PAGE         ((uint16_t)0x00AB)

/* Page status definitions */
#define ERASED                ((uint16_t)0xFFFF)     /* Page is empty */
#define RECEIVE_DATA          ((uint16_t)0xEEEE)     /* Page is marked to receive data */
#define VALID_PAGE            ((uint16_t)0x0000)     /* Page containing valid data */

/* Valid pages in read and write defines */
#define READ_FROM_VALID_PAGE  ((uint8_t)0x00)
#define WRITE_IN_VALID_PAGE   ((uint8_t)0x01)

/* Page full define */
#define PAGE_FULL             ((uint8_t)0x80)

/* Variables' number */
// #define NB_OF_VAR             ((uint8_t)0x03) // minem
#define NB_OF_VAR             ((uint8_t)0x04) // minem

/* Exported types ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Exported macro ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Exported functions ------------------------------------------------------- */
uint16_t EE_Init(void);
uint16_t EE_ReadVariable(uint16_t VirtAddress, uint16_t* Data);
uint16_t EE_WriteVariable(uint16_t VirtAddress, uint16_t Data);

#endif /* __EEPROM_H */

/******************* (C) COPYRIGHT 2011 STMicroelectronics *****END OF FILE****/
```

*eeprom.c*:

```c
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file    EEPROM_Emulation/src/eeprom.c 
  * @author  MCD Application Team
  * @version V1.0.0
  * @date    10-October-2011
  * @brief   This file provides all the EEPROM emulation firmware functions.
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * THE PRESENT FIRMWARE WHICH IS FOR GUIDANCE ONLY AIMS AT PROVIDING CUSTOMERS
  * WITH CODING INFORMATION REGARDING THEIR PRODUCTS IN ORDER FOR THEM TO SAVE
  * TIME. AS A RESULT, STMICROELECTRONICS SHALL NOT BE HELD LIABLE FOR ANY
  * DIRECT, INDIRECT OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES WITH RESPECT TO ANY CLAIMS ARISING
  * FROM THE CONTENT OF SUCH FIRMWARE AND/OR THE USE MADE BY CUSTOMERS OF THE
  * CODING INFORMATION CONTAINED HEREIN IN CONNECTION WITH THEIR PRODUCTS.
  *
  * <h2><center>&copy; COPYRIGHT 2011 STMicroelectronics</center></h2>
  ******************************************************************************
  */ 

/** @addtogroup EEPROM_Emulation
  * @{
  */ 

/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "eeprom.h"
    
// #include "eeprom_write.h" // minem; Error[Li005]: no definition for "VirtAddVarTab" [referenced from C:\ARM_STM32F407_PRJ\IAR-STM32F407VE\WebServer\Flash Debug\Obj\eeprom_emulation\eeprom.o]           


/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/

/* Global variable used to store variable value in read sequence */
uint16_t DataVar = 0;

/* Virtual address defined by the user: 0xFFFF value is prohibited */
extern uint16_t VirtAddVarTab[NB_OF_VAR];

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
/* Private functions ---------------------------------------------------------*/
static FLASH_Status EE_Format(void);
static uint16_t EE_FindValidPage(uint8_t Operation);
static uint16_t EE_VerifyPageFullWriteVariable(uint16_t VirtAddress, uint16_t Data);
static uint16_t EE_PageTransfer(uint16_t VirtAddress, uint16_t Data);

/**
  * @brief  Restore the pages to a known good state in case of page's status
  *   corruption after a power loss.
  * @param  None.
  * @retval - Flash error code: on write Flash error
  *         - FLASH_COMPLETE: on success
  */
uint16_t EE_Init(void)
{
  uint16_t PageStatus0 = 6, PageStatus1 = 6;
  uint16_t VarIdx = 0;
  uint16_t EepromStatus = 0, ReadStatus = 0;
  int16_t x = -1;
  uint16_t  FlashStatus;

  /* Get Page0 status */
  PageStatus0 = (*(__IO uint16_t*)PAGE0_BASE_ADDRESS);
  /* Get Page1 status */
  PageStatus1 = (*(__IO uint16_t*)PAGE1_BASE_ADDRESS);

  /* Check for invalid header states and repair if necessary */
  switch (PageStatus0)
  {
    case ERASED:
      if (PageStatus1 == VALID_PAGE) /* Page0 erased, Page1 valid */
      {
        /* Erase Page0 */
        FlashStatus = FLASH_EraseSector(PAGE0_ID,VOLTAGE_RANGE);
        /* If erase operation was failed, a Flash error code is returned */
        if (FlashStatus != FLASH_COMPLETE)
        {
          return FlashStatus;
        }
      }
      else if (PageStatus1 == RECEIVE_DATA) /* Page0 erased, Page1 receive */
      {
        /* Erase Page0 */
        FlashStatus = FLASH_EraseSector(PAGE0_ID, VOLTAGE_RANGE);
        /* If erase operation was failed, a Flash error code is returned */
        if (FlashStatus != FLASH_COMPLETE)
        {
          return FlashStatus;
        }
        /* Mark Page1 as valid */
        FlashStatus = FLASH_ProgramHalfWord(PAGE1_BASE_ADDRESS, VALID_PAGE);
        /* If program operation was failed, a Flash error code is returned */
        if (FlashStatus != FLASH_COMPLETE)
        {
          return FlashStatus;
        }
      }
      else /* First EEPROM access (Page0&1 are erased) or invalid state -> format EEPROM */
      {
        /* Erase both Page0 and Page1 and set Page0 as valid page */
        FlashStatus = EE_Format();
        /* If erase/program operation was failed, a Flash error code is returned */
        if (FlashStatus != FLASH_COMPLETE)
        {
          return FlashStatus;
        }
      }
      break;

    case RECEIVE_DATA:
      if (PageStatus1 == VALID_PAGE) /* Page0 receive, Page1 valid */
      {
        /* Transfer data from Page1 to Page0 */
        for (VarIdx = 0; VarIdx < NB_OF_VAR; VarIdx++)
        {
          if (( *(__IO uint16_t*)(PAGE0_BASE_ADDRESS + 6)) == VirtAddVarTab[VarIdx])
          {
            x = VarIdx;
          }
          if (VarIdx != x)
          {
            /* Read the last variables' updates */
            ReadStatus = EE_ReadVariable(VirtAddVarTab[VarIdx], &DataVar);
            /* In case variable corresponding to the virtual address was found */
            if (ReadStatus != 0x1)
            {
              /* Transfer the variable to the Page0 */
              EepromStatus = EE_VerifyPageFullWriteVariable(VirtAddVarTab[VarIdx], DataVar);
              /* If program operation was failed, a Flash error code is returned */
              if (EepromStatus != FLASH_COMPLETE)
              {
                return EepromStatus;
              }
            }
          }
        }
        /* Mark Page0 as valid */
        FlashStatus = FLASH_ProgramHalfWord(PAGE0_BASE_ADDRESS, VALID_PAGE);
        /* If program operation was failed, a Flash error code is returned */
        if (FlashStatus != FLASH_COMPLETE)
        {
          return FlashStatus;
        }
        /* Erase Page1 */
        FlashStatus = FLASH_EraseSector(PAGE1_ID, VOLTAGE_RANGE);
        /* If erase operation was failed, a Flash error code is returned */
        if (FlashStatus != FLASH_COMPLETE)
        {
          return FlashStatus;
        }
      }
      else if (PageStatus1 == ERASED) /* Page0 receive, Page1 erased */
      {
        /* Erase Page1 */
        FlashStatus = FLASH_EraseSector(PAGE1_ID, VOLTAGE_RANGE);
        /* If erase operation was failed, a Flash error code is returned */
        if (FlashStatus != FLASH_COMPLETE)
        {
          return FlashStatus;
        }
        /* Mark Page0 as valid */
        FlashStatus = FLASH_ProgramHalfWord(PAGE0_BASE_ADDRESS, VALID_PAGE);
        /* If program operation was failed, a Flash error code is returned */
        if (FlashStatus != FLASH_COMPLETE)
        {
          return FlashStatus;
        }
      }
      else /* Invalid state -> format eeprom */
      {
        /* Erase both Page0 and Page1 and set Page0 as valid page */
        FlashStatus = EE_Format();
        /* If erase/program operation was failed, a Flash error code is returned */
        if (FlashStatus != FLASH_COMPLETE)
        {
          return FlashStatus;
        }
      }
      break;

    case VALID_PAGE:
      if (PageStatus1 == VALID_PAGE) /* Invalid state -> format eeprom */
      {
        /* Erase both Page0 and Page1 and set Page0 as valid page */
        FlashStatus = EE_Format();
        /* If erase/program operation was failed, a Flash error code is returned */
        if (FlashStatus != FLASH_COMPLETE)
        {
          return FlashStatus;
        }
      }
      else if (PageStatus1 == ERASED) /* Page0 valid, Page1 erased */
      {
        /* Erase Page1 */
        FlashStatus = FLASH_EraseSector(PAGE1_ID, VOLTAGE_RANGE);
        /* If erase operation was failed, a Flash error code is returned */
        if (FlashStatus != FLASH_COMPLETE)
        {
          return FlashStatus;
        }
      }
      else /* Page0 valid, Page1 receive */
      {
        /* Transfer data from Page0 to Page1 */
        for (VarIdx = 0; VarIdx < NB_OF_VAR; VarIdx++)
        {
          if ((*(__IO uint16_t*)(PAGE1_BASE_ADDRESS + 6)) == VirtAddVarTab[VarIdx])
          {
            x = VarIdx;
          }
          if (VarIdx != x)
          {
            /* Read the last variables' updates */
            ReadStatus = EE_ReadVariable(VirtAddVarTab[VarIdx], &DataVar);
            /* In case variable corresponding to the virtual address was found */
            if (ReadStatus != 0x1)
            {
              /* Transfer the variable to the Page1 */
              EepromStatus = EE_VerifyPageFullWriteVariable(VirtAddVarTab[VarIdx], DataVar);
              /* If program operation was failed, a Flash error code is returned */
              if (EepromStatus != FLASH_COMPLETE)
              {
                return EepromStatus;
              }
            }
          }
        }
        /* Mark Page1 as valid */
        FlashStatus = FLASH_ProgramHalfWord(PAGE1_BASE_ADDRESS, VALID_PAGE);
        /* If program operation was failed, a Flash error code is returned */
        if (FlashStatus != FLASH_COMPLETE)
        {
          return FlashStatus;
        }
        /* Erase Page0 */
        FlashStatus = FLASH_EraseSector(PAGE0_ID, VOLTAGE_RANGE);
        /* If erase operation was failed, a Flash error code is returned */
        if (FlashStatus != FLASH_COMPLETE)
        {
          return FlashStatus;
        }
      }
      break;

    default:  /* Any other state -> format eeprom */
      /* Erase both Page0 and Page1 and set Page0 as valid page */
      FlashStatus = EE_Format();
      /* If erase/program operation was failed, a Flash error code is returned */
      if (FlashStatus != FLASH_COMPLETE)
      {
        return FlashStatus;
      }
      break;
  }

  return FLASH_COMPLETE;
}

/**
  * @brief  Returns the last stored variable data, if found, which correspond to
  *   the passed virtual address
  * @param  VirtAddress: Variable virtual address
  * @param  Data: Global variable contains the read variable value
  * @retval Success or error status:
  *           - 0: if variable was found
  *           - 1: if the variable was not found
  *           - NO_VALID_PAGE: if no valid page was found.
  */
uint16_t EE_ReadVariable(uint16_t VirtAddress, uint16_t* Data)
{
  uint16_t ValidPage = PAGE0;
  uint16_t AddressValue = 0x5555, ReadStatus = 1;
  uint32_t Address = EEPROM_START_ADDRESS, PageStartAddress = EEPROM_START_ADDRESS;

  /* Get active Page for read operation */
  ValidPage = EE_FindValidPage(READ_FROM_VALID_PAGE);

  /* Check if there is no valid page */
  if (ValidPage == NO_VALID_PAGE)
  {
    return  NO_VALID_PAGE;
  }

  /* Get the valid Page start Address */
  PageStartAddress = (uint32_t)(EEPROM_START_ADDRESS + (uint32_t)(ValidPage * PAGE_SIZE));

  /* Get the valid Page end Address */
  Address = (uint32_t)((EEPROM_START_ADDRESS - 2) + (uint32_t)((1 + ValidPage) * PAGE_SIZE));

  /* Check each active page address starting from end */
  while (Address > (PageStartAddress + 2))
  {
    /* Get the current location content to be compared with virtual address */
    AddressValue = (*(__IO uint16_t*)Address);

    /* Compare the read address with the virtual address */
    if (AddressValue == VirtAddress)
    {
      /* Get content of Address-2 which is variable value */
      *Data = (*(__IO uint16_t*)(Address - 2));

      /* In case variable value is read, reset ReadStatus flag */
      ReadStatus = 0;

      break;
    }
    else
    {
      /* Next address location */
      Address = Address - 4;
    }
  }

  /* Return ReadStatus value: (0: variable exist, 1: variable doesn't exist) */
  return ReadStatus;
}

/**
  * @brief  Writes/upadtes variable data in EEPROM.
  * @param  VirtAddress: Variable virtual address
  * @param  Data: 16 bit data to be written
  * @retval Success or error status:
  *           - FLASH_COMPLETE: on success
  *           - PAGE_FULL: if valid page is full
  *           - NO_VALID_PAGE: if no valid page was found
  *           - Flash error code: on write Flash error
  */
uint16_t EE_WriteVariable(uint16_t VirtAddress, uint16_t Data)
{
  uint16_t Status = 0;

  /* Write the variable virtual address and value in the EEPROM */
  Status = EE_VerifyPageFullWriteVariable(VirtAddress, Data);

  /* In case the EEPROM active page is full */
  if (Status == PAGE_FULL)
  {
    /* Perform Page transfer */
    Status = EE_PageTransfer(VirtAddress, Data);
  }

  /* Return last operation status */
  return Status;
}

/**
  * @brief  Erases PAGE and PAGE1 and writes VALID_PAGE header to PAGE
  * @param  None
  * @retval Status of the last operation (Flash write or erase) done during
  *         EEPROM formating
  */
static FLASH_Status EE_Format(void)
{
  FLASH_Status FlashStatus = FLASH_COMPLETE;

  /* Erase Page0 */
  FlashStatus = FLASH_EraseSector(PAGE0_ID, VOLTAGE_RANGE);

  /* If erase operation was failed, a Flash error code is returned */
  if (FlashStatus != FLASH_COMPLETE)
  {
    return FlashStatus;
  }

  /* Set Page0 as valid page: Write VALID_PAGE at Page0 base address */
  FlashStatus = FLASH_ProgramHalfWord(PAGE0_BASE_ADDRESS, VALID_PAGE);

  /* If program operation was failed, a Flash error code is returned */
  if (FlashStatus != FLASH_COMPLETE)
  {
    return FlashStatus;
  }

  /* Erase Page1 */
  FlashStatus = FLASH_EraseSector(PAGE1_ID, VOLTAGE_RANGE);

  /* Return Page1 erase operation status */
  return FlashStatus;
}

/**
  * @brief  Find valid Page for write or read operation
  * @param  Operation: operation to achieve on the valid page.
  *   This parameter can be one of the following values:
  *     @arg READ_FROM_VALID_PAGE: read operation from valid page
  *     @arg WRITE_IN_VALID_PAGE: write operation from valid page
  * @retval Valid page number (PAGE or PAGE1) or NO_VALID_PAGE in case
  *   of no valid page was found
  */
static uint16_t EE_FindValidPage(uint8_t Operation)
{
  uint16_t PageStatus0 = 6, PageStatus1 = 6;

  /* Get Page0 actual status */
  PageStatus0 = (*(__IO uint16_t*)PAGE0_BASE_ADDRESS);

  /* Get Page1 actual status */
  PageStatus1 = (*(__IO uint16_t*)PAGE1_BASE_ADDRESS);

  /* Write or read operation */
  switch (Operation)
  {
    case WRITE_IN_VALID_PAGE:   /* ---- Write operation ---- */
      if (PageStatus1 == VALID_PAGE)
      {
        /* Page0 receiving data */
        if (PageStatus0 == RECEIVE_DATA)
        {
          return PAGE0;         /* Page0 valid */
        }
        else
        {
          return PAGE1;         /* Page1 valid */
        }
      }
      else if (PageStatus0 == VALID_PAGE)
      {
        /* Page1 receiving data */
        if (PageStatus1 == RECEIVE_DATA)
        {
          return PAGE1;         /* Page1 valid */
        }
        else
        {
          return PAGE0;         /* Page0 valid */
        }
      }
      else
      {
        return NO_VALID_PAGE;   /* No valid Page */
      }

    case READ_FROM_VALID_PAGE:  /* ---- Read operation ---- */
      if (PageStatus0 == VALID_PAGE)
      {
        return PAGE0;           /* Page0 valid */
      }
      else if (PageStatus1 == VALID_PAGE)
      {
        return PAGE1;           /* Page1 valid */
      }
      else
      {
        return NO_VALID_PAGE ;  /* No valid Page */
      }

    default:
      return PAGE0;             /* Page0 valid */
  }
}

/**
  * @brief  Verify if active page is full and Writes variable in EEPROM.
  * @param  VirtAddress: 16 bit virtual address of the variable
  * @param  Data: 16 bit data to be written as variable value
  * @retval Success or error status:
  *           - FLASH_COMPLETE: on success
  *           - PAGE_FULL: if valid page is full
  *           - NO_VALID_PAGE: if no valid page was found
  *           - Flash error code: on write Flash error
  */
static uint16_t EE_VerifyPageFullWriteVariable(uint16_t VirtAddress, uint16_t Data)
{
  FLASH_Status FlashStatus = FLASH_COMPLETE;
  uint16_t ValidPage = PAGE0;
  uint32_t Address = EEPROM_START_ADDRESS, PageEndAddress = EEPROM_START_ADDRESS+PAGE_SIZE;

  /* Get valid Page for write operation */
  ValidPage = EE_FindValidPage(WRITE_IN_VALID_PAGE);

  /* Check if there is no valid page */
  if (ValidPage == NO_VALID_PAGE)
  {
    return  NO_VALID_PAGE;
  }

  /* Get the valid Page start Address */
  Address = (uint32_t)(EEPROM_START_ADDRESS + (uint32_t)(ValidPage * PAGE_SIZE));

  /* Get the valid Page end Address */
  PageEndAddress = (uint32_t)((EEPROM_START_ADDRESS - 2) + (uint32_t)((1 + ValidPage) * PAGE_SIZE));

  /* Check each active page address starting from begining */
  while (Address < PageEndAddress)
  {
    /* Verify if Address and Address+2 contents are 0xFFFFFFFF */
    if ((*(__IO uint32_t*)Address) == 0xFFFFFFFF)
    {
      /* Set variable data */
      FlashStatus = FLASH_ProgramHalfWord(Address, Data);
      /* If program operation was failed, a Flash error code is returned */
      if (FlashStatus != FLASH_COMPLETE)
      {
        return FlashStatus;
      }
      /* Set variable virtual address */
      FlashStatus = FLASH_ProgramHalfWord(Address + 2, VirtAddress);
      /* Return program operation status */
      return FlashStatus;
    }
    else
    {
      /* Next address location */
      Address = Address + 4;
    }
  }

  /* Return PAGE_FULL in case the valid page is full */
  return PAGE_FULL;
}

/**
  * @brief  Transfers last updated variables data from the full Page to
  *   an empty one.
  * @param  VirtAddress: 16 bit virtual address of the variable
  * @param  Data: 16 bit data to be written as variable value
  * @retval Success or error status:
  *           - FLASH_COMPLETE: on success
  *           - PAGE_FULL: if valid page is full
  *           - NO_VALID_PAGE: if no valid page was found
  *           - Flash error code: on write Flash error
  */
static uint16_t EE_PageTransfer(uint16_t VirtAddress, uint16_t Data)
{
  FLASH_Status FlashStatus = FLASH_COMPLETE;
  uint32_t NewPageAddress = EEPROM_START_ADDRESS;
  uint16_t OldPageId=0;
  uint16_t ValidPage = PAGE0, VarIdx = 0;
  uint16_t EepromStatus = 0, ReadStatus = 0;

  /* Get active Page for read operation */
  ValidPage = EE_FindValidPage(READ_FROM_VALID_PAGE);

  if (ValidPage == PAGE1)       /* Page1 valid */
  {
    /* New page address where variable will be moved to */
    NewPageAddress = PAGE0_BASE_ADDRESS;

    /* Old page ID where variable will be taken from */
    OldPageId = PAGE1_ID;
  }
  else if (ValidPage == PAGE0)  /* Page0 valid */
  {
    /* New page address  where variable will be moved to */
    NewPageAddress = PAGE1_BASE_ADDRESS;

    /* Old page ID where variable will be taken from */
    OldPageId = PAGE0_ID;
  }
  else
  {
    return NO_VALID_PAGE;       /* No valid Page */
  }

  /* Set the new Page status to RECEIVE_DATA status */
  FlashStatus = FLASH_ProgramHalfWord(NewPageAddress, RECEIVE_DATA);
  /* If program operation was failed, a Flash error code is returned */
  if (FlashStatus != FLASH_COMPLETE)
  {
    return FlashStatus;
  }

  /* Write the variable passed as parameter in the new active page */
  EepromStatus = EE_VerifyPageFullWriteVariable(VirtAddress, Data);
  /* If program operation was failed, a Flash error code is returned */
  if (EepromStatus != FLASH_COMPLETE)
  {
    return EepromStatus;
  }

  /* Transfer process: transfer variables from old to the new active page */
  for (VarIdx = 0; VarIdx < NB_OF_VAR; VarIdx++)
  {
    if (VirtAddVarTab[VarIdx] != VirtAddress)  /* Check each variable except the one passed as parameter */
    {
      /* Read the other last variable updates */
      ReadStatus = EE_ReadVariable(VirtAddVarTab[VarIdx], &DataVar);
      /* In case variable corresponding to the virtual address was found */
      if (ReadStatus != 0x1)
      {
        /* Transfer the variable to the new active page */
        EepromStatus = EE_VerifyPageFullWriteVariable(VirtAddVarTab[VarIdx], DataVar);
        /* If program operation was failed, a Flash error code is returned */
        if (EepromStatus != FLASH_COMPLETE)
        {
          return EepromStatus;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  /* Erase the old Page: Set old Page status to ERASED status */
  FlashStatus = FLASH_EraseSector(OldPageId, VOLTAGE_RANGE);
  /* If erase operation was failed, a Flash error code is returned */
  if (FlashStatus != FLASH_COMPLETE)
  {
    return FlashStatus;
  }

  /* Set new Page status to VALID_PAGE status */
  FlashStatus = FLASH_ProgramHalfWord(NewPageAddress, VALID_PAGE);
  /* If program operation was failed, a Flash error code is returned */
  if (FlashStatus != FLASH_COMPLETE)
  {
    return FlashStatus;
  }

  /* Return last operation flash status */
  return FlashStatus;
}

/**
  * @}
  */ 

/******************* (C) COPYRIGHT 2011 STMicroelectronics *****END OF FILE****/
```

Function for writing and reading:

```c
void eewrite()
{
  /* Unlock the Flash Program Erase controller */
  FLASH_Unlock();
  /* EEPROM Init */
  EE_Init();
  EE_WriteVariable(VirtAddVarTab[0],1111);
  EE_ReadVariable(VirtAddVarTab[0], &VarDataTab[0]);
  printf("VarDataTab[0]: %d\n\r",VarDataTab[0]);
  /* Locks the FLASH Program Erase controller */
  FLASH_Lock(); // minem
}
```

`eeprom.h/.c` are from st.com: [en.stsw-stm32066.zip](https://www.st.com/en/embedded-software/stsw-stm32066.html)

`stm32f4xx_flash.icf` must be changed in IAR -> Options -> Linker -> Config -> Edit -> Memory Regions : End: to 0x0807FFFF (from 0x089FFFFF)

Comment: Be aware that if you use the same flash memory bank for EEPROM emulation as is used for code storage, then during a program or erase operation the CPU will be halted. This can last for a very long time (mS). There are workarounds but they are not straight-forward. IIRC the STM32L series have separate EEPROM regions.

Comment: There is a watchdog.